# Discord.js message.embeds[0] not outputting anything;

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to program a discord bot to play hangman except I'm doing it in embeds to learn how they work. Unfortunately, I've been at a roadblock trying to resend my embed after they got a letter right or not.

I tried to follow the discord.js guide and use the `message.embeds[0]` command but it doesn't output anything. The example embed just outputs with the field I added after.

Here's the important part:

```js
const gameEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(embedColour)
    .setTitle('Hangman')
    .setDescription('Play hangman in discord!')
    .addFields(
        { name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word', value: seenWord },
    );
const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(receivedEmbed).addFields({ name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word', value: seenWord });
```

```js
message.channel.send(gameEmbed);
        collector.on('collect', m => {
            if (!knownLetters.includes(m.content.toLowerCase()) || !incorrectLetters.includes(m.content.toLowerCase())) {
                if (wordLetters.includes(m.content.toLowerCase())) {
                    message.channel.send('Congratulations! You guessed a letter correctly!');
                    knownLetters[wordLetters.indexOf(m.content.toLowerCase())] = m.content.toLowerCase();
                    updateWord();
                    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
                }
```

And the whole program, in case there's anything you need:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'hangman',
    description: 'Play hangman in discord!',
    run(message, args, Discord) {
        const words = require('./words.json');
        const chosenWord = words.words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 981)];
        const wordLetters = new Array();
        const knownLetters = new Array();
        const incorrectLetters = new Array();
        let seenWord = '';
        let i;

        const embedColour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

        for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
            wordLetters.push(chosenWord[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
            knownLetters.push('\\_', ' ');
        }

        function updateWord() {
            for (i = 0; i < knownLetters.length; i++) {
                seenWord += knownLetters[i];
            }
        }
        updateWord();

        const filter = m => m.author.id === m.author.id && !m.author.bot && m.content.toLowerCase().length == 1;
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
            time: 1000 * 30,
        });

        const gameEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(embedColour)
            .setTitle('Hangman')
            .setDescription('Play hangman in discord!')
            .addFields(
                { name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word', value: seenWord },
            );
        const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(receivedEmbed).addFields({ name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word', value: seenWord });

        message.channel.send(chosenWord);
        message.channel.send(gameEmbed);
        collector.on('collect', m => {
            if (!knownLetters.includes(m.content.toLowerCase()) || !incorrectLetters.includes(m.content.toLowerCase())) {
                if (wordLetters.includes(m.content.toLowerCase())) {
                    message.channel.send('Congratulations! You guessed a letter correctly!');
                    knownLetters[wordLetters.indexOf(m.content.toLowerCase())] = m.content.toLowerCase();
                    updateWord();
                    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
                }
                else {
                    message.channel.send('I\'m sorry, that letter is not in the word. Try again!');
                }
            }
            else {
                message.chanel.send('You have already guessed that letter. Try again!');
            }
        });

        collector.on('end', (collected) => {
            message.channel.send(`done, collected ${collected.size} messages`);
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.embeds` is an empty array as the user only sends a simple message, so you can't use that. What you can do is... change the field you added to your embed and send that again:

```js
gameEmbed.fields[0] = {
  name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word',
  value: seenWord,
};
message.channel.send(gameEmbed);
```

I've made quite a few changes (and added comments) in your code, but at least it seems to be working now:

```js
const words = require('./words.json');
const chosenWord = words.words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
// destructuring is easier than a for loop
const wordLetters = [...chosenWord];
// don't use new Array(), use [] instead
const knownLetters = [];
const incorrectLetters = [];
let seenWord = '';

for (let i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
  knownLetters.push('\\_', ' ');
}

function updateWord() {
  // you need to reset seenWord, not just add new characters to it
  seenWord = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < knownLetters.length; i++) {
    seenWord += knownLetters[i];
  }
}
updateWord();

// m.author.id === m.author.id doesn't make sense
const filter = (m) => !m.author.bot && m.content.toLowerCase().length == 1;
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
  time: 1000 * 30,
});

const gameEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  // you can use RANDOM to set the colour to random :)
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setTitle('Hangman')
  .setDescription('Play hangman in discord!')
  .addFields({
    name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word',
    value: seenWord,
  });

message.channel.send(chosenWord);
message.channel.send(gameEmbed);

collector.on('collect', (m) => {
  const letter = m.content.toLowerCase();
  // try to return early to avoid ifs inside ifs inside ifs
  if (knownLetters.includes(letter) || incorrectLetters.includes(letter)) {
    return message.chanel.send(
      'You have already guessed that letter. Try again!',
    );
  }

  if (!wordLetters.includes(letter)) {
    // don't forget to add letter to incorrectLetters
    incorrectLetters.push(letter);
    return message.channel.send(
      "I'm sorry, that letter is not in the word. Try again!",
    );
  }

  message.channel.send('Congratulations! You guessed a letter correctly!');

  // you need to double the index if you added spaces between the underscores
  // TODO: it only replaces the first occurrence, you need to replace all!
  knownLetters[wordLetters.indexOf(letter) * 2] = letter;
  updateWord();
  // simply update the first field
  gameEmbed.fields[0] = {
    name: chosenWord.length.toString() + '-letter word',
    value: seenWord,
  };
  // and send the same embed
  message.channel.send(gameEmbed);
});

collector.on('end', (collected) => {
  message.channel.send(`done, collected ${collected.size} messages`);
});
```